# Checking specific folders when git on Jenkins

Tags: git, grails, jenkins

I am using Jenkins / Git to check out a Grails project.
The Grails project is in a sub directory for the Git project I check out.

So that when Git does the checkout, I end up with

```
.jenkins/jobs/my_jenkins_job/workspace/git_base_dir/grails_project_dir/grails_files
```

on my filesystem

I want:

```
.jenkins/jobs/my_jenkins_job/workspace/grails_files
```

Now I could run a shell to move files around but I prefer a cleaner way.

In the branch specifier on Jenkins I have tried:

```
develop/grails_project_dir/grails_files
```

But this just gives:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Is there any way I can get the git plugin to just check out specific folders in a git project?

Thanks

Comment: git doesnt supprt that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only nor jenkins plugin

Comment: It's not possible just make a git repo (in this case "grails_files" folder) inside your big git repo?

Comment: @Udy I'll accept that as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git doesnt support that nor jenkins plugin.

you can see the link below for more info:

[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: This is actually available in more recent versions of Jenkins/Git 2.1.0 for Jenkins and 1.7.0 for Git.

Comment: @Udy It would be helpful if you updated your answer given the current state of Jenkins

Answer (score 16):

**The accepted answer is outdated...**

As of version 2.1.0 of Jenkins-Git plugin this is supported: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21809

You will need Git version 1.7.0+ which added the sparse checkout functionality.

If you want to do a sparse-checkout yourself you can have a look at https://gist.github.com/sumardi/5559896

Comment: Thanks @030, I removed the failing link and added another post with more hands-on information about sparse-checkout.